# I want to express this code with for loop or function

Tags: r

I have a large data frame.

As you can see, a pattern exists code below:

```
data_1<-data_1
data_2<-data_2 %>% filter(rowSums(data_2[,1:1])==0)
data_3<-data_3 %>% filter(rowSums(data_3[,1:2])==0)
data_4<-data_4 %>% filter(rowSums(data_4[,1:3])==0)
data_5<-data_5 %>% filter(rowSums(data_5[,1:4])==0)
data_6<-data_6 %>% filter(rowSums(data_6[,1:5])==0)
data_7<-data_7 %>% filter(rowSums(data_7[,1:6])==0)
data_8<-data_8 %>% filter(rowSums(data_8[,1:7])==0)
data_9<-data_9 %>% filter(rowSums(data_9[,1:8])==0)
data_10<-data_10 %>% filter(rowSums(data_10[,1:9])==0)
data_11<-data_11 %>% filter(rowSums(data_11[,1:10])==0)
data_12<-data_12 %>% filter(rowSums(data_12[,1:11])==0)
data_13<-data_13 %>% filter(rowSums(data_13[,1:12])==0)
data_14<-data_14 %>% filter(rowSums(data_14[,1:13])==0)
data_15<-data_15 %>% filter(rowSums(data_15[,1:14])==0)
data_16<-data_16 %>% filter(rowSums(data_16[,1:15])==0)
data_17<-data_17 %>% filter(rowSums(data_17[,1:16])==0)
data_18<-data_18 %>% filter(rowSums(data_18[,1:17])==0)
data_19<-data_19 %>% filter(rowSums(data_19[,1:18])==0)
data_20<-data_20 %>% filter(rowSums(data_20[,1:19])==0)
data_21<-data_21 %>% filter(rowSums(data_21[,1:20])==0)
```

I tried to make loop like this

```
for(i in 1:21){
  data_i <- data_i %>% filter(rowSums(data_i[,1:i-1])==0)
```

but, `data_i` is far away from my intention.

how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your life will become much easier if you put your data frames into a list and then loop through the list.

Answer (score 2):

**1) for** We use the test data in the Note at the end based on the built in anscombe data frame that comes with R.  It is best to keep related data frames in a list so we first create such a list L and then iterate over it producing a new list L2 so that we don't overwrite the original list. Keeping the input and output separate makes it easier to debug.

We could alternately write `seq_along(L)[-1]` as `seq(2, length(L))` and we could alternately write `seq_len(i-1)` as `seq(1, i-1)`. Note that if `DF` is a data frame then `DF[, 1]` is the first column as a column *vector* but `DF[, 1, drop = FALSE]` is a one column *data frame*.

No packages are used.

```
L <- mget(ls(pattern = "^data_\\d+$"))
L2 <- L
for(i in seq_along(L)[-1]) {
  Li <- L[[i]]
  Sum <- rowSums(Li[, seq_len(i-1), drop = FALSE])
  L2[[i]] <- Li[Sum == 0, ]
}
```

**2) lapply** Alternately we could use `lapply`:

```
L <- mget(ls(pattern = "^data_\\d+$"))
L2 <- L
L2[-1] <- lapply(seq_along(L)[-1], function(i) {
  Li <- L[[i]]
  Sum <- rowSums(Li[, seq_len(i-1), drop = FALSE])
  Li[Sum == 0, ]
})
```

**3) Map** or use Map

```
L3 <- L
f3 <- function(d, i) {
  Sum <- rowSums(d[, seq_len(i-1), drop = FALSE])
  d[Sum == 0, ]
}
L3[-1] <- Map(f3, L[-1], seq_along(L)[-1])
```

or special case the first element like this.  Note that it will take the component names from the first argument to Map after the function so it is important that f4 be defined so that that argument is L.

```
f4 <- function(d, i) {
  if (i == 1) d 
  else {
    Sum <- rowSums(d[, seq_len(i-1), drop = FALSE])
    d[Sum == 0, ]
  }
}
L4 <- Map(f4, L, seq_along(L))
```

### Note

```
# create test data
data_1 <- anscombe
data_1[1, 1] <- 0
data_2 <- 10 * anscombe
data_2[2, 1:2] <- 0
data_3 <- 100 * anscombe
data_3[3, 1:3] <- 0
```